# How to subplot eyr-diagram in matlab?

Tags: matlab, object, subplot

I have this matlab code:

```
h1= commscope.eyediagram('SamplingFrequency',sample_rate,'SamplesPerSymbol',sample_rate/B,...
   'SymbolsPerTrace',4,'RefreshPlot', 'on','MaximumAmplitude',1.2);
figure(100)
subplot(2,2,1);
plot(h1);

subplot(2,2,3);
plot(h1)
```

I want to plot h1 in two subplots but it opens new figures and doesn't put it in the same figure. why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `commscope.eyediagram` function, but I think that `h1` already creates a plot and not data.

I tried your code with data

```
h1 = 1:10;
```

and it worked perfectly.

If my guess is correct, you should get the data from `h1` by using one of the `get` methods.
Something like:

```
data=get(h,'XData');
```

and then re-write your code like that:

```
figure(100)
subplot(2,2,1);
plot(data);

subplot(2,2,3);
plot(data)
```